# Autolayout different constraints for landscape and portrait mode

Tags: ios, autolayout, masonry-ios-osx

I use Masonry library that helps with adding constraints programmatically.
Its fine, but now i faced the problem that i need to uninstall and add new constraints after user rotate device from landscape to portrait. I tried rather "brutal" solution, it did change constraints, but, in fraction of second i could see "old" constraints. Is there are easy way to add/remove constraints after user rotate device? That is what i tried (it work, but as i described above in a fraction of second i could see "old" frames):

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        [bottomRight mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

            NSLog(@"We are on landscape");
            make.top.equalTo(upperRight.mas_bottom).with.offset(20);
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX).with.offset(20);
            make.right.equalTo(bottomRightRight.mas_left).with.offset(-20);
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).with.offset(-100);

            make.width.equalTo(bottomRightRight);

        }]; }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Swapped");
        [bottomRight mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

            make.top.equalTo(upperRight.mas_bottom).with.offset(200);
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX).with.offset(200);
            make.right.equalTo(bottomRightRight.mas_left).with.offset(-200);
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).with.offset(-200);

            make.width.equalTo(bottomRightRight);

        }];

    }

}
```

Comment: `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is depricated since ios8. If you don't have support pre-ios8 os you can try to use
`- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection`. 
An NSLayoutConstraint can be activated and deactivated instead of add and remove. I don't know how Masonry wraps NSLayoutConstraints, but you may can find the analogical feature there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to uninstall and add new constraints after user rotate device from landscape to portrait. I tried rather "brutal" solution, it did change constraints, but, in fraction of second i could see "old" constraints.

But that's the problem: you are changing the constraints *after* the user rotates the device. So *you* are the one who is causing the phenomenon you don't like, i.e. that this happens a fraction of a second *after* the rotation is over.

The correct solution is to change constraints *before* the user rotates the device. If you do that, the change of constraints will be magically animated to match the rotation and the change will appear absolutely seamless.

For example, if this is an iPhone app, you can implement the view controller's `willTransitionToTraitCollection...` and do your constraint changes there, and the change will be magically matched to the rotation.

Comment: No, this is iPad version :) By the way, that is the method for iOS 8 and later, would you please provide soliution for iOS 7? We need to support "old" devices.

Comment: Still the same kind of answer. For iPad use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`. For iOS 7 you get a different set of "will" events. But it's all the same. Use "will", not "did". That is the point of my answer.

Comment: i find -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration perfectly suitable for my needs, however look like it is depreciated. viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator work perfectly as well but only for iOS > 8..